# Designing and printing notebook covers

Tags: print-design

I am currently designing notebook covers and I am looking to print them by myself at home. I just would like to know if anyone has any experience with printing notebook covers and if there is a particular printer ink or paper that is more durable than a regular one. Or if it's better to take the job to a printing company.